# Is the following integral setup to find the volume correct?

Tags: calculus, volume

I need to find the volume of the cylinderical column standing on the area common to parabola $y= x^2$ and $x =y^2$ as base and cutoff by the surface  $z= 1+y-x^2$.

So I set up the integral as :

Volume = $\displaystyle\int_0^1\int_{x^2}^{\sqrt{x}} \int _0 ^{1+y-x^2}dzdydx$

My question is : Is this setup  correct ?

Comment: (My previous - and now deleted - comment was wrong). This looks right to me (assuming that the plane $z=0$ is one of the bounding surfaces: you do not make that clear in the statement of the problem).

Comment: @NickD Here,the cylinderical column is standing on area common to given parabolas as base, hence   $z =0$ is this correct ?

Comment: I guess it's right: I'm just a wee bit paranoid, that's all.

Comment: @NickD haha :P,Actually even I get  a little confused on these questions involving to set up an integral  due to which I have to ask and verify even such simple questions,     By the way can you tell me how should I  visualize in such problems I can solve the easy questions , But for tougher one It becomes harder,